# filter the column of 3500+ book's text . How to make my code fast to work on heavy data in NLP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

i am working on a data where every row of column has a huge text appromixately a book in every row
so when i apply the below code of NLP for 10-50 rows it work fine  on 100 -200 raws it work but  takes 10 mins 
when i apply on 3000 books or rows it was not giving me the output even after 2 hours so is there is any way to make fast this code or is there is another method to get the output quickly??

```
 import re
 import nltk
 nltk.download('stopwords')
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
 corpus = []
 for i in range(0,3500):
     review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', str(dt["TEXT"][i]))
     review = review.lower()
     review = review.split()
     ps=  PorterStemmer()
     review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]review = ' '.join(review)
      corpus.append(review)
```

Answer (score 0):

One improvement can be to store a set of stopwords instead of converting every time in a list comprehension. This improvement can be huge depending upon size of the stop-word list and number of times call to convert list to set.

You can run the following code at this online compiler.
Link : https://onlinegdb.com/HJVVgw4cI

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer

a = ['a','b','c','d']
sent = 'abc in my word'


start = timer()
for i in range(0,10000):
    a = [i for i in sent if not i in set(a)]
end = timer()
print(end - start)

start = timer()
b = set(a)
for i in range(0,10000):
    a = [i for i in sent if not i in b]
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

result of the above code is:

```
0.36757875100011006                                                                                                            
0.09286667400010629
```

In your code, this will be something like this.

```py
import re
 import nltk
 nltk.download('stopwords')
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
 corpus = []
 stopword_set = set(stopwords.words('english'))
 for i in range(0,3500):
     review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', str(dt["TEXT"][i]))
     review = review.lower()
     review = review.split()
     ps=  PorterStemmer()
     review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in stopword_set]review = ' '.join(review)
      corpus.append(review)
```

I suspect one more improvement can be done in regex. regex can be slow if we have to compile it every time.

```py
# this can be optimized in your code....
review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', str(dt["TEXT"][i]))
```

Comment: hello brother thanks for this  but i am still not able to combine this both code can you please tell how to combine this code